# How to write to a file without overwriting current contents?

Tags: python, file-io

```
with open("games.txt", "w") as text_file:
    print(driver.current_url)
    text_file.write(driver.current_url + "\n")
```

I'm using this code right now, but when it writes to the file it overwrites the old content. How can I simply add to it without erasing the content that's already there.

Comment: The option "a" will allow writing only at the end of the file.

Use open("games.txt", "r+") if you want keep the old content but also be allowed to overwrite parts of the initial content with what you want by file seeking.

The list of available options might also be useful: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Instead of `"w"` use `"a"` (append) mode with [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open) function:

```
with open("games.txt", "a") as text_file:
```