# File reading and editing in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to read and write a file at the same time?

I'm writing a script that accepts user inputs and also supplies the latest data in the database, but my current code just overwrites the previous data.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file)

Comment: If you are asking why your current code is behaving that way, you'd need to share the code by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44080542/edit) it, otherwise we may only be able to recommend answers many of the other similar questions, such as [Python write to file without overwriting current txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441803/python-write-to-file-without-overwriting-current-txt)