# Twitter bot not saving tweet IDs in text file

Tags: python, twitter, bots

I am trying to make a Twitter bot that will reply to tweet automatically but I do not want it to reply to tweets it has already replied to so I am trying to have the tweet IDs saved to a text document and have the bot reference it for the last seen ID but it is not updating the text document.

```
FILE_NAME = 'last_seen.txt'

def read_last_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open(FILE_NAME, 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen_id

def store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, last_seen_id):
    file_write = open(FILE_NAME, 'w')
    file_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    file_write.close()
    return
tweets = api.mentions_timeline(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended')


for tweet in reversed(tweets):

    if '#botting' in tweet.full_text.lower():
        print(str(tweet.id) + ' - ' + tweet.full_text)
        api.update_status('@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' This is a bot.', tweet.id)
        store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, tweet.id)
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

When I simplified the tweets for testing purposes, the program just overwrrote the previous entries.  [Repl here](https://repl.it/join/zrwkssud-themagicbean)

So  your writing program is not advancing past previous entries.  I think you want "a" mode and not "w."  You also want to probably put new lines or a break character in between entries so when scanning for a match you don't get false matches.

[Python write to file without overwriting current txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441803/python-write-to-file-without-overwriting-current-txt)

Comment: ... so if that helped please mark as answered. I know the community as a whole probably sees it as a basic, already answered question, but as one of few I could answer I'd appreciate the mark.